# Cordova Phonegap - Android geolocation shows error: Application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions error

Tags: android, xml, cordova, geolocation

On browser and iOS platforms the location works well and shows required data. 
On the Android it shows current error:

> Application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions error

**resources/Config.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <!-- Set DisallowOverscroll to true to avoid bounce effect -->
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0" />
    <preference name="PageLength" value="0" />
    <preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page" />
    <preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated" />
    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="HandleOpenUrl">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVHandleOpenURL" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="IntentAndNavigationFilter">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVIntentAndNavigationFilter" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="GestureHandler">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGestureHandler" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="PushNotification">
        <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Vibration">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVVibration" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVAccelerometer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCompass" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CameraUsesGeolocation" value="false" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Globalization">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGlobalization" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCapture" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
    <feature name="Console">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" />
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*.websitename.com" />
     <allow-navigation href="https://*.youtube.com" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
</widget>
```

**Android/res/xml/config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <!-- Set DisallowOverscroll to true to avoid bounce effect -->
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0" />
    <preference name="PageLength" value="0" />
    <preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page" />
    <preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated" />
    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="HandleOpenUrl">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVHandleOpenURL" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="IntentAndNavigationFilter">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVIntentAndNavigationFilter" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="GestureHandler">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGestureHandler" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="PushNotification">
        <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Vibration">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVVibration" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVAccelerometer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCompass" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CameraUsesGeolocation" value="false" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Globalization">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGlobalization" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCapture" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
    <feature name="Console">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" />    
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*.websitename.com" />
     <allow-navigation href="https://*.youtube.com" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
</widget>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.cordova.hellocordova" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="app name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
</manifest>
```

**Plugins/org.apache.cordova.geolocation/plugin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
  or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
  distributed with this work for additional information
  regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
  to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
  "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
  with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
  software distributed under the License is distributed on an
  "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
  KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
  specific language governing permissions and limitations
  under the License.
-->

<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" id="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.12">
    <name>Geolocation</name>
    <description>Cordova Geolocation Plugin</description>
    <license>Apache 2.0</license>
    <keywords>cordova,geolocation</keywords>
    <repo>https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git</repo>
    <issue>https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB/component/12320638</issue>
    <!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        </config-file>
    </platform>
    <!-- amazon-fireos -->
    <platform name="amazon-fireos">
        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        </config-file>
    </platform>
    <!-- ios -->
    <platform name="ios">
        <js-module src="www/Coordinates.js" name="Coordinates">
            <clobbers target="Coordinates" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/PositionError.js" name="PositionError">
            <clobbers target="PositionError" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/Position.js" name="Position">
            <clobbers target="Position" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/geolocation.js" name="geolocation">
            <clobbers target="navigator.geolocation" />
        </js-module>

        <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="Geolocation">
                <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <header-file src="src/ios/CDVLocation.h" />
        <source-file src="src/ios/CDVLocation.m" />
        <framework src="CoreLocation.framework" />

        <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
            <string></string>
        </config-file>
    </platform>
    <!-- blackberry10 -->
    <platform name="blackberry10">
        <js-module src="www/blackberry10/GeolocationProxy.js" name="GeolocationProxy">
            <runs />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/Coordinates.js" name="Coordinates">
            <clobbers target="Coordinates" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/PositionError.js" name="PositionError">
            <clobbers target="PositionError" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/Position.js" name="Position">
            <clobbers target="Position" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/geolocation.js" name="geolocation">
            <clobbers target="navigator.geolocation" />
        </js-module>

        <config-file target="www/config.xml" parent="/widget">
            <feature name="Geolocation" value="Geolocation"/>
        </config-file>

        <config-file target="www/config.xml" parent="/widget/rim:permissions">
          <rim:permit>read_geolocation</rim:permit>
        </config-file>
    </platform>

    <!-- ubuntu -->
    <platform name="ubuntu">
        <js-module src="www/Coordinates.js" name="Coordinates">
            <clobbers target="Coordinates" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/PositionError.js" name="PositionError">
            <clobbers target="PositionError" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/Position.js" name="Position">
            <clobbers target="Position" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/geolocation.js" name="geolocation">
            <clobbers target="navigator.geolocation" />
        </js-module>

        <source-file src="src/ubuntu/geolocation.cpp" />
        <header-file src="src/ubuntu/geolocation.h" />
        <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="Geolocation">
                <param policy_group="location" policy_version="1" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>
    </platform>

    <!-- wp7 -->
    <platform name="wp7">

        <config-file target="Properties/WMAppManifest.xml" parent="/Deployment/App/Capabilities">
            <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION" />
        </config-file>

        <source-file src="src/wp/Geolocation.cs" />
    </platform>

    <!-- wp8 -->
    <platform name="wp8">

        <config-file target="Properties/WMAppManifest.xml" parent="/Deployment/App/Capabilities">
            <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION" />
        </config-file>

        <source-file src="src/wp/Geolocation.cs" />
    </platform>

    <!-- windows8 -->
    <platform name="windows8">
        <config-file target="package.appxmanifest" parent="/Package/Capabilities">
            <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
        </config-file>

        <js-module src="src/windows/GeolocationProxy.js" name="GeolocationProxy">
            <runs />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/Coordinates.js" name="Coordinates">
            <clobbers target="Coordinates" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/PositionError.js" name="PositionError">
            <clobbers target="PositionError" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/Position.js" name="Position">
            <clobbers target="Position" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/geolocation.js" name="geolocation">
            <clobbers target="navigator.geolocation" />
        </js-module>
    </platform>

    <!-- windows universal apps (Windows 8.1, Windows Phone 8.1, Windows 8.0) -->
    <platform name="windows">
        <config-file target="package.appxmanifest" parent="/Package/Capabilities">
            <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
        </config-file>

        <js-module src="src/windows/GeolocationProxy.js" name="GeolocationProxy">
            <runs />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/Coordinates.js" name="Coordinates">
            <clobbers target="Coordinates" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/PositionError.js" name="PositionError">
            <clobbers target="PositionError" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/Position.js" name="Position">
            <clobbers target="Position" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/geolocation.js" name="geolocation">
            <clobbers target="navigator.geolocation" />
        </js-module>
    </platform>

    <!-- firefoxos -->
    <platform name="firefoxos">
      <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
          <permission name="geolocation" description="Required for accessing user location." />
      </config-file>

        <js-module src="src/firefoxos/GeolocationProxy.js" name="GeolocationProxy">
            <runs />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/Coordinates.js" name="Coordinates">
            <clobbers target="Coordinates" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/PositionError.js" name="PositionError">
            <clobbers target="PositionError" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/Position.js" name="Position">
            <clobbers target="Position" />
        </js-module>

        <js-module src="www/geolocation.js" name="geolocation">
            <clobbers target="navigator.geolocation" />
        </js-module>
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

**Javascript for fetching location:**

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  }

  function init() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionSuccess, positionError);
  }

  function onDeviceReady(){

  }

  function positionSuccess(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById('lat').value = latitude;
    document.getElementById('lon').value = longitude;
  }

  function positionError(error) {
    alert(error.message);
  }
</script>
```

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

In case if someone needs an answer, I found it here: https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues/743

I just updated the plugin and the error disappeared:

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.geolocation
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

Comment: Yes! In Visual Studio config.xml -> DELETE the current plugin, then update plugin cordova-plugin-geolocation.

Comment: @pollaris do you just mean.... delete the row, save and reinsert it?? Or something else, like, create the apk before to insert it again?

Comment: I uninstalled the plugin.  Then I re-installed it.  Double click on config.xml to open up the plugin manager.

Answer (score 2):

In your ionic project Open config.xml

Add below code at last before `</widget>`

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="4.0.1">`
       <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App uses geolocation to determine where you are." />
</plugin>

<platform name="android">
       <uses-permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
       <uses-permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
       <uses-permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
</platform>
```

Using the above change, your app automatically calls a permission dialog when your app uses location details for the first time after a fresh install.